# Load balancing Apache with 2 machines total

Tags: apache, load-balancing

Load balancing and clustering are still new concepts to me so forgive me if my question is not clear.

I Currently have 1 machine running apache.

I plan on buying a 1 new machine to use for the same purpose as the existing apache machine.
It will NOT replace the first machine but instead they will work together to preform the same function(run apache).

*I do NOT have a hardware load balancer or the ability to buy a another machine to act as a software load balancer.

My goal is:

1. lower the load required on both machines.
2. use one machine as a backup should the other fail.

Question:
What is the best or easiest way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, There is no master/slave configuration in webservers unlike the dns servers. You can reduce the load on each machine by sharing the websites to equal. That means migrate half of the websites to the new server to reduce the load/effort of the old server.

To work as a backup if one fails,
You can clone the new server as old and create 2 new any custom name servers pointing them to the new server IP. add that name servers to all domains from corresponding registrar end. So if one fails websites will load from the other. :)

Comment: what if I setup apache's mod_proxy_balancer on port 80 to have one member as the other server and one as localhost with a webserver on a different port? or would that be too inefficient?